# Is aleph-3 the cardinality of all the surfaces that exists?

Tags: set-theory

If the general continuum hypothesis (GHC) is true, what is the cardinality of all the geometric surfaces that exists?

If I'm right, Aleph-1 is the cardinal of the set of all the points, Aleph-2 the cardinal of the set of all the curves, then, is is Aleph-3 the cardinal of all the surfaces that exist?

Comment: No, the cardinality of the set of planes in three-space is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ (if CH is assumed it is $\aleph_1$).

Comment: Note that there is a large difference between the set of planes, and the set of _surfaces_, just as there is a large difference between the set of lines and the set of curves. There are $|\Bbb R|$ many planes, but there are a whole lot more surfaces. Whether there are significantly more surfaces than curves, though, I am more uncertain about.

Comment: I totally agree with @Arthur : maybe the OP will want to rephrase the question with "surfaces" instead of "planes" ?

Comment: @Arthur: Unless you're including significant pathology (parameter functions just being Borel measurable is not enough) in what a "surface" is, the cardinality will still be continuum.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I would assume that taking a curve in the plane and extending it orthogonally to $\Bbb R^3$ ought to be within the definition of "surface" in this context. Doesn't that alone give more than $|\Bbb R|$ surfaces?

Comment: @Arthur: No, since there are only continuum many curves in the plane, unless "curve" is generalized to something like the graph of any function. For any notion of curve that excludes significant pathological notions (by this, I'm talking about well beyond being everywhere discontinuous or graphs of functions that are dense in the plane), there are only continuum many curves (despite what Gamow wrote at the end of Chapter I of his 1947 book **One Two Three...Infinity**).

Comment: Oh god. Again with that $\aleph_1,\aleph_2$ crap??? :(

Comment: I think I should correct this to "surfaces" instead of "planes". I'm simply trying to find an intuitive meaning of Aleph-3 using a geometric example. Please note I'm assuming GHC is true.

Comment: What is GHC?${}$

Comment: General Continuum Hypothesis

Comment: The cardinal of $\Bbb R^3$ is the cardinal of $\Bbb R$ which is $c=2^{\aleph_0}.$ So  the set of   $all$  subsets of $\Bbb R^3$ has cardinal $2^c.$ And GCH implies $2^c=\aleph_2.$

Comment: So, GHC is **G**eneralized **C**ontinuum **H**ypothesis?

Comment: "*I'm simply trying to find an intuitive meaning of Aleph-3 using a geometric example.*" I can think of a couple of somewhat natural examples (they're not particularly geometric), but I recommend that you ask this as a new question and skip the GCH irrelevancies and simply ask for natural examples of sets having cardinality $2^{2^c}.$

Comment: No doubt the OP has been influence, directly or indirectly, by the physicist George Gamow's popular book *One, Two, Three, Infinity*, where he wrote: "But the number of all geometrical points, though larger than the number of all integer and fractional numbers, is not the largest one known to mathematicians. In fact it was found that the variety of all possible curves, including those of most unusual shapes, has a larger membership than the collection of all geometrical points, and thus has to be described by the third number of the infinite sequence."

Answer (score 1):

Cardinality and dimension aren't related in any way. One standard example of this is the fact that $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N}^2,\mathbb{N}^3$, etc. all have the same cardinality $\aleph_0$, and similarly the line, plane, and space ($\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^3$) have the same cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$; this question - unless you're defining "surface" in a very weird way - is another example.

The following fact (and its extension mentioned below) kills basically every version of this question:

> The number of locally [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Compact_spaces) [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Separable_spaces) [metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space), up to [isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Isometries), is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

**Ignore the precise result above if you haven't seen the terms involved before**; the important point is that this covers a truly gigantic class of "shapes." It includes e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$, every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, every metric space that can be homeomorphically embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, ... Basically, the vast majority the non-deliberately-pathological metric spaces you're ever likely to see.

The proof in some detail (modulo an exercise) is below, but it may be difficult to follow if you haven't had some background already; let me first give a quick summary of what's going on.

A curve, surface, ... , basically any "nice shape" is determined by its "approximate data." Let me give an example of what this means. Suppose I told you that I have a "shape" $M$ (e.g. the line $\mathbb{R}$) with a certain sequence of points $\{p_0, p_1, p_2, ...\}$ which forms a countable dense set (e.g., the rationals in $\mathbb{R}$), and moreover I told you roughly how far apart from each other they are: for each $i, j\in\mathbb{N}$, and each $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, I told you whether $d(p_i, p_j)<q$. For instance, if $M=\mathbb{R}$, $p_0=0$, and $p_1=1$, then I told you $d(p_0, p_1)<2$ but $d(p_0, p_1)\not<1$.

It turns out that from these facts, you can completely reconstruct $M$! This is surprising at first, but if you think about [how the real numbers are constructed from the rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_from_Cauchy_sequences) I think you'll see why this might be true. (And if you haven't seen this construction before, it's awesome and totally worth spending time on to learn in detail - even besides its importance, it's just *really cool*.) In particular, a good first exercise is to show that from this data - which on the face of it is only about *rational* distances - you can figure out the *exact* distances between the points in the sequence.

The proof then finishes by counting the number of such "collections of data." This winds up being easy, and ultimately is just the observation that "countable times countable times countable is countable" mentioned above.

---

So here's the proof modulo an exercise, as promised:

*Proof:* We show how each such space can be represented up to isometry by a subset of $\mathbb{N}$; since there are $2^{\aleph_0}$-many such subsets, this will prove the result.

Since $M$ is separable metric space, fix some countable dense sequence $C\subseteq M$, and let $$H=\{\langle i, j, q\rangle: i, j\in \mathbb{N}, d(c_i, c_j)\le q\}$$ be the "approximating set" of $M$ via $C$.

> Exercise: show that $H$ determines $C$ completely: if $M_0, M_1$ are locally compact separable metric spaces, $C_0, C_1$ are countable dense sequences, and $H_0, H_1$ are the resulting approximating sets, $H_0=H_1$ implies $M_0\cong M_1$.

Conversely, every locally compact separable metric space has an approximating set. So the number of locally compact separable metric spaces up to isometry is at most the number of sets of the above form. But each approximating set is a subset of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}$; this latter set is countable, so has $2^{\aleph_0}$-many subsets, and we're done.

Comment: While this answer is correct, and maybe it is as simple as possible, it feels like you're answering a question "explain it like I'm five" with "well, assume that you have two years of undergraduate math under your belt". Which I am all in favor. I just hate the type of questions...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've tried to edit it so that it will be more appropriate for the OP. I'm actually largely sympathetic to these questions; a lot of popular texts do a great job of building *interest* in higher infinities, but a terrible job in giving correct intuition, and I am happy to try to resolve that issue. (When I was much younger I read a truly terrible "pop set theory" book and thought I'd solved CH by showing $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert=2^{\aleph_0}$; if nothing else, I consider this my penance. :P)

Comment: I know. I know. I am all in favor of popular mathematics, and even more so, popular set theory. But so much of it has been written by... well... physicists, or people so far from the topic that they have no idea what they are talking about.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Physicist in you world are the BAD people to write something about math? Wow.

Comment: @DRF: In general? Probably not as bad as historians, but definitely not who I would want to write a popular *set theory* book. But if you want to misinterpret my comment, be my guest.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Wasn't meant to be misinterpreting or inflamatory. More fascination at your standards. I'm usually happy when people I can get to do things are half way competent. to liken it to your comparison most of the people writing popular set theory books would be sports journalists.

Comment: @DRF: I would probably have qualms to how a majority of mathematicians would treat set theory in a popular or non popular writing. It is the unfortunate and often misunderstood child of mathematics. And the reason I wouldn't presume to write a popular quantum mechanics book, I wouldn't expect a physicist to write a good popular set theory book. I don't know why reality should be any different.